# plot a data frame but don't know how to extract variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame df like this:

```
            1999      2002      2005      2008

POINT    1323759.8  883223.8  963392.9  734288.6

NONPOINT 5518185.3 4254247.0 4043390.2 2438866.9

ON-ROAD   183895.1  154222.2  134291.8  107384.1

NON-ROAD  307126.5  344087.5  313628.1  183666.2
```

I want to make a plot of annual emission changes respectively for four types "POINT" "NONPOINT" "ON-ROAD" "NON-ROAD". But I don't know how to quote the variables. Maybe this format is what I want.

```
qplot(year,emission,data=df,facets = type~.)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `melt`.

```
#Recreate input data 
sample_input = data.frame(
   type = c("POINT", "NONPOINT", "ON-ROAD", "NON-ROAD"),
   A = rnorm(4, 1e4),
   B = rnorm(4, 1e4),
   C = rnorm(4, 1e4),
   D = rnorm(4, 1e4)
 )

 colnames(sample_input) = c("type", "1999", "2002", "2005", "2008")

 df = reshape2::melt(sample_input, measure.vars = c("1999", "2002", "2005", "2008"),
                       variable.name = "year", value.name = "emission")

 library(ggplot2)

 qplot(year,emission,data=df,facets = type~.)
```